# codeigniter redirect from a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a site entirely on codeigniter .I have set my default controller as cuff. 
so whenever users type the domain name it takes the control to that controller.

```
class Cuff extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
       }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    public function navigate()
    {
        echo "test";
        exit;
}

}
```

In my index view I want an anchor to navigate to a function in my default controller . 
so when I write 
`<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>navigate">our collection</a>` , it says page not found .

I have even set the base url like this

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```

Cant seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: you can debug it, by printing the href  in the view itself...

Comment: change <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>navigate">our collection</a> to 
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>cuff/navigate">our collection</a>

Comment: even if i try to access any function from my default controller it says page not found . 
Example : www.domain.com/cuff/navigate . is it because of the way i have set my base url ?? ...plus my default controller is cuff.. Would that make a difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the controller name

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>cuff/navigate">our collection</a>
```

Comment: i tried that too.. :-) ..still doesnt work ...plus when i try accessing the navigate function directly from the url , it says page not found . 

For Eg : www.domain.com/cuff/navigate

Comment: Have you set htaccess rule to remove index.php from url? Try accessing www.domain.com/index.php/cuff/navigate

Comment: yes...it says no input file specified . 
this is my 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /testCI/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Set `$config['base_url'] ='';`

In your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|favicon|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Make sure your controller is in controller's folder (not any subfolder) and is properly named `cuff.php`

Try navigating to `http://yoursite/cuff/navigate`

If you still see errors try rewriting the last line in `.htaccess` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

(without question mark).

Please tell if that helps!

EDIT: and your links better all be in this form:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('cuff/navigate');?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your routing.

Edit your **routes.php** (located in the folder **../application/config/**) and add the code below:

```
$route['navigate'] = "Cuff/navigate";
```

For more information regarding Codeingiter URI Routing:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you use

```
"<?php echo site_url();?>/cuff/navigate">our collection</a>
```